Extract values from multiple XML columns each with multiple nodes
I have a table myTable with three XML columns of the same structure:
CREATE TABLE myTable 
(
    Field1 XML,
    Field2 XML,
    Field3 XML
);

INSERT INTO myTable (Field1, Field2, Field3) 
VALUES 
    ('<div class="Class1">
          <p>123</p>
          <p>456</p>
      </div>',
     '<div class="Class2">
          <p>abc</p>
          <p>def</p>
          </div>',
     '<div class="Class3">
          <p>XYZ</p>
          <p>AEIOU</p>
      </div>')

I would like to extract the values between the <p> tags, which I am able to accomplish for a single field using nodes(). However, when I try to bring in the other fields, it creates a cross reference of all the values, rather than showing each one's first, second, etc.
This is my code:
SELECT
    a.b.value('.','nvarchar(max)'),
    c.d.value('.','nvarchar(max)'),
    e.f.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
FROM
    myTable
CROSS APPLY 
    myTable.Field1.nodes('div/p') a(b)
CROSS APPLY 
    myTable.Field2.nodes('div/p') c(d)
CROSS APPLY 
    myTable.Field3.nodes('div/p') e(f)

Which produces output like this:
Field1 Field2 Field3
----------------------
123    abc    XYZ
123    abc    AEIOU
123    def    XYZ
123    def    AEIOU
456    abc    XYZ
456    abc    AEIOU
456    def    XYZ
456    def    AEIOU

I would like the output to be:
Field1 Field2 Field3
----------------------
123    abc    XYZ
456    def    AEIOU

The XML columns will always have the same number of nodes for a single row, but the number of nodes can vary from row to row.
Is there any way to accomplish this within a single query?

Is there always 2 p nodes in each div node?

Side note: Tables don't have "fields" that have columns.

@ThomA not always 2, but always the same number. Edited the post to include that

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

@YitzhakKhabinsky I added the DDL, should meet all those requirements now

Annoyingly (as far as I am aware), you can't return the position value from a node, you can only filter to it (such as demonstrated in this answer from Roger Wolf).
Instead what you could do is create a Tally of for the number of nodes in the first XML column to get a row for each p node for each ID. Then you can filter on the position() in your call to the nodes method and return 1 row per position.
As you're on 2019, you don't have access to GENERATE_SERIES, so I use a UDF for the tally:
--Create the UDF
CREATE FUNCTION [fn].[Tally] (@LastNumber bigint, @Zero bit) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN

    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT 0 AS I
        WHERE @Zero = 0
          AND @LastNumber IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP (ISNULL(@LastNumber,0))
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6, N N7) --Up to 10,000,000 rows
    SELECT I
    FROM Tally T;
GO
--Create sample data
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (YourID int IDENTITY,
                            XML1 xml,
                            XML2 xml,
                            XML3 xml);
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES('<div class="Class1">
  <p>123</p>
  <p>456</p>
</div>','<div class="Class2">
<p>abc</p>
<p>def</p>
</div>','<div class="Class3">
<p>XYZ</p>
<p>AEIOU</p>
</div>');
GO
--The actual solution
WITH NodeCounts AS(
    SELECT YT.YourID,
           COUNT(*) AS Nodes
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY YT.XML1.nodes('/div/p') div(p)
    GROUP BY YT.YourID)
SELECT YT.YourID,
       X1.p.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS Field1,
       X2.p.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS Field2,
       X3.p.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS Field3
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN NodeCounts NC ON YT.YourID = NC.YourID
     CROSS APPLY fn.Tally(NC.Nodes,1) T
     CROSS APPLY YT.XML1.nodes('/div/p[position() = sql:column("T.I")]') X1(p)
     CROSS APPLY YT.XML2.nodes('/div/p[position() = sql:column("T.I")]') X2(p)
     CROSS APPLY YT.XML3.nodes('/div/p[position() = sql:column("T.I")]') X3(p);

Alternatively, you could achieve this without a Tally and use ROW_NUMBER in the CTE. This might be more performant (I suggest racing your horses):
WITH NodeCounts AS(
    SELECT YT.YourID,
           YT.XML1,
           YT.XML2,
           YT.XML3,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YT.YourID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY YT.XML1.nodes('/div/p') div(p))
SELECT NC.YourID,
       X1.p.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS Field1,
       X2.p.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS Field2,
       X3.p.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS Field3
FROM NodeCounts NC
     CROSS APPLY NC.XML1.nodes('/div/p[position() = sql:column("NC.I")]') X1(p)
     CROSS APPLY NC.XML2.nodes('/div/p[position() = sql:column("NC.I")]') X2(p)
     CROSS APPLY NC.XML3.nodes('/div/p[position() = sql:column("NC.I")]') X3(p);

db<>fiddle

This answer worked best for me as it allowed me to bring in other non-XML fields from the same table (which I neglected to include in my original question)

Please try the following solution.
The following XQuery p.value('for $i in . return count(../p[. << $i]) + 1', 'INT') AS Seq allows us easily return position of an XML element. The rest is just joins based on seq(ence) values.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,Col1 XML,Col2 XML,Col3 XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl(Col1,Col2,Col3) 
VALUES 
('<div class="Class1">
  <p>123</p>
  <p>456</p>
</div>)'
,'<div class="Class2">
<p>abc</p>
<p>def</p>
</div>'
 ,'<div class="Class3">
<p>XYZ</p>
<p>AEIOU</p>
</div>');
-- DDL and sample data population, start

WITH rs1 AS
(
    SELECT t.id
        , p.value('for $i in . return count(../p[. << $i]) + 1', 'INT') AS Seq
        , p.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS col1
    FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY Col1.nodes('/div/p') div(p)
), rs2 AS
(
    SELECT t.id
        , p.value('for $i in . return count(../p[. << $i]) + 1', 'INT') AS Seq
        , p.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS col2
    FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY Col2.nodes('/div/p') div(p)
), rs3 AS
(
    SELECT t.id
        , p.value('for $i in . return count(../p[. << $i]) + 1', 'INT') AS Seq
        , p.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS col3
    FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY Col3.nodes('/div/p') div(p)
)
SELECT rs1.ID, col1, col2, col3 
FROM rs1 
    INNER JOIN rs2 ON rs2.ID = rs1.ID AND rs2.Seq = rs1.Seq
    INNER JOIN rs3 ON rs3.ID = rs1.ID AND rs3.Seq = rs1.Seq;

Output



ID
col1
col2
col3




1
123
abc
XYZ


1
456
def
AEIOU




This works but why not prepivot the xml fields so you don't have to copypaste so much

Unfortunately, my table doesn't have an ID (not my creation...) and I have other columns that I need to bring in, apologies for not including that in the original question... this is a great answer though and hopefully helps someone else in need

Any database table suppose to have a primary key. That's why I used it in the answer.

Crimping the Yitzhak XML trick, here's a condensed version:
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  p.value('for $i in . return count(../p[. << $i]) + 1', 'INT') AS Seq
    ,   p.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS col
    ,   x.id
    FROM    (
        VALUES 
            ('<div class="Class1">
              <p>123</p>
              <p>456</p>
            </div>)'
            ,'<div class="Class2">
            <p>abc</p>
            <p>def</p>
            </div>'
             ,'<div class="Class3">
            <p>XYZ</p>
            <p>AEIOU</p>
            </div>')
        ) data (Col1, Col2, Col3)
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES  (CAST(Col1 AS XML), 1)
        ,   (CAST(Col2 AS XML), 2)
        ,   (CAST(Col3 AS XML), 3)
        ) x (col, id)
    CROSS APPLY x.col.nodes('/div/p') div(p)
    ) x
PIVOT(MAX(col) FOR id IN ([1],[2],[3])) pv


First, we expand the columns into 3 rows with XML, ID (x subquery) and then performing the nodes CROSS APPLY and extract the Position and  value
Then, by PIVOTing by he ID, we pivot the rows back into columns, grouped by the Sequence.

Output:



Seq
1
2
3




1
123
abc
XYZ


2
456
def
AEIOU



